# An interesting connection between the Möbius function and the parity of the number of sublattices of index $n$ in generic $3$-dimensional lattice

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-lattices, mobius-function

I recently discovered an interesting connection between the following two On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) sequences: [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001) and [A209635](http://oeis.org/A209635). More specifically, there seems to be an interesting connection between the reduction of [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001) modulo $2$ and the OEIS sequence [A209635](http://oeis.org/A209635).

Let [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001)$(n)$ denote the number of [sublattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) of index $n$ in generic 3-dimensional lattice.

Let [A000265](http://oeis.org/A000265)$(n)$ denote the largest odd divisor of $n$.

Reduce the sequence [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001) modulo 2, yielding:

$$(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$$

Now compute the integer sequence $(|\mu($[A000265](http://oeis.org/A000265)$(n))|  :  n \in \mathbb{N} )$:

$$(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$$

We have that [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001)$(n)(\text{mod $2$}) = |\mu($[A000265](http://oeis.org/A000265)$(n))| $ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots 80$.

We have that [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001)$(n)(\text{mod $2$})$ is not equal to $|\mu($[A000265](http://oeis.org/A000265)$(n))| $ if and only if $n$ is an entry in the following integer sequence, which we denote by  $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (assuming this sequence is infinite):

$$(81, 162, 243, 324, 405, 486, 567, 625, 648, 810, 891, 972, 1053, 
1134, 1215, 1250, 1296,  \ldots)$$

This integer sequence is not currently in the OEIS. Now consider the sequence $(\frac{a_{n}}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$:

$$(81,81,81,81,81,81,81,\frac{625}{8},72,81,81,81,81,81,81,\frac{625}{8},\frac{1296}{17},\frac{153}{2},81,81,81,81,   \ldots)$$

This intuitively seems to be a very strange sequence, since the integer $81$ at first seems to appear frequently but not in a 'predictable' way.

I have several questions regarding the connection between [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001) and [A209635](http://oeis.org/A209635) described above.

**Question 1:** Is there any intuitive number-theoretic explanation as to 'why' the parity of [A001001](http://oeis.org/A001001) is so similar to the integer sequence $(|\mu($[A000265](http://oeis.org/A000265)$(n))|  :  n \in \mathbb{N} )$?

**Question 2:** What is $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

**Question 3:** What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}$? Some plots  illustrating the apparent convergence of the sequence $\left( \frac{a_{n}}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ are given below.

[image: An illustration of the sequence $\left( \frac{a_{n}}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ generated using *Mathematica*.]

[image: Another illustration of the sequence $\left( \frac{a_{n}}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$.]

[image]

Comment: Can you use clear mathematical formulas, thank you. And suppose that $n$ is odd and $f(n) = \prod_{p^k | n} g(p^k)$ where $g(p^k)$ is even when $k \ge 2$, odd otherwise. Then $f(n) \bmod 2 = |\mu(n)|$

Comment: so the answer is "[FORMULA If n = Product p^m, a(n) = Product (p^(m + 1) - 1)(p^(m + 2) - 1)/(p - 1)(p^2 - 1). Or, a(n) = Sum_{d|n} sigma(n/d)*d^2, Dirichlet convolution of A000290 and A000203.](http://oeis.org/A001001)"